# How to reorder array of Core Data Objects and reorder it's Int attributes in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, core-data, swift3

Let's say I have an array of Core Data objects.

```
let array = [Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4, Object5, Object6, Object7]
```

Each object has an attribute named indexValue : Int64

Firstly these objects have these values of indexValue attribute:

```
Object1 has indexValue = 1
Object2 has indexValue = 2
Object3 has indexValue = 3
Object4 has indexValue = 4
Object5 has indexValue = 5
Object6 has indexValue = 6
Object7 has indexValue = 7
```

Now let's say, I deleted Object3 and Object6 for example, and now objects in my array have the following indexValues

```
Object1 has indexValue = 1
Object2 has indexValue = 2
Object4 has indexValue = 4
Object5 has indexValue = 5
Object7 has indexValue = 7
```

After deletion I want to reorder this array in the following manner:
I want to change indexValue attributes of this array to the following states:

```
Object1 has indexValue = 1
Object2 has indexValue = 2
Object4 has indexValue = 3
Object5 has indexValue = 4
Object7 has indexValue = 5
```

The main difficulty is to keep the old order while giving the new values of indexValue. I'm looking for an algorithm to accomplish this in Swift 3.

Comment: So you want the indexValue to take the value of the real index of each object in the array?

Comment: @nbloqs `i++` does not work in Swift 3 and `indexValue` is `Int64` and one-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, use this function and pass the ordered – with missing indexes – array.

You have to replace `MyObject` with the actual custom type containing the `indexValue` attribute and add the code to save the managed object context.

```
func reindex(items : [MyObject])
{
    for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
        item.indexValue = Int64(index + 1)
    }
    // save the context
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I've been looking for!